# SSRS report showing different data when it should match

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2016

I have a report that is called from a text box action.  When I run the report in my Visual Studio looking at production data I get 9 records returned.  When I deploy the report and run it I only get 5 records.  I have deleted the report on the report server and re-deployed but I am getting the same results.  I have added a footer and removed columns and changed heading so I know that the version that is on the report server is the one in my Visual Studio project.  I have checked all the filters on the matrix and can't figure out why the report doesn't match.

[image: Visual Studio]

[image: Report Server]

Any suggestions on where else to look for why the data isn't matching?

Comment: Check the datasource on the server you deployed to. By default, overwriting datasources is switched off so it will only be set once on the server when you deploy. If you then change your datasource in your dev environment (Visual Studio) and then re-deploy, only the report design will be updated not the datasource(s). You can change this in the project properties but safer to check it on the server first to be sure that it is actually wrong.

Comment: Yes I checked the data source and data set is using the correct one (a shared Data Source). I didn't change the query embedded in the report.

Comment: The next step would be to run a trace on the SQL Server while execute the report and see what query is actually being executed.